# PHP Mysql - Add 1 to a value, Next value subtract 1 all values from database ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, if-statement

I have beeen cracking my brain for hours to solve this logic in php but with no succes in site and tried googling it was not clear. Here it goes.

I have this serial ID values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 as id in my database. Using SELECT statement to call the values was ok. But here is my problem, Using PHP after getting the above from the database, I want one to be added to 1 from the database, one subtracted from 2 from the database, one added to 3 from the database, one subtracted from 4 from the database etc. Each operation should be added to an array which will be called later using a FOR loop.

I thought of using array, if then else, i just cant rap my fingers around it, can someone help

Comment: Check for `even/odd`

Comment: "one to be added to 1 from the database, one subtracted from 2 from the database, one added..." I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Can you give an example result?

Comment: The above values 1-10 are ID values which are auto incremented. Using the SELECT statement, was able to read them. But i need for the 1st value 1, 1 added to it and stored in array(), for the 2nd value 2, one is subtracted and stored in the same array etc hope i make some sense

Comment: You want an array of functions?

Answer (score 1):

`$val + (($val & 1)<<1) -1`
adds 1 to odd numbers and substracts 1 from even numbers.